# Submit donation form as product with instant checkout?

Tags: 8, commerce

Wondering what's the best way to go about using Commerce 2 to present a single page donation form to the user with an instant buy/donate button? I.e. no add to checkout then going through the checkout procedure.

User should be able to enter any donation amount into the form, along with their contact details etc.

Comment: If you're asking about donate button, you can simply create a form using PayPal [check here](https://www.paypal.com/buttons/paymentbuttons/donate/create). Once created a form you can then integrate that in Drupal easily. PayPal also supports other buttons, check out [here](https://www.paypal.com/in/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_donate-intro-outside).

Comment: Thanks but no, I need variable, arbitrary pricing and also need to be able to track donations (orders) and donors (customers) in Drupal. There's also a requirement for a full physical product shop. So I need full ecommerce not just a simple PayPal payment button.

Comment: Also another issue with the PayPal button approach is (I assume) that it wouldn't actually submit the custom Drupal form the donor had filled out. Extra code would be required to submit the form and it wouldn;t be synced to whether the donor actually went through with the payment or not.